# Date converted to plain text in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I use importdata() to grab a legacy file and use it in a spreadsheet.
This file contains date's in the yyyymmdd format (i.e. 20150520)
I wish to filter out dates what contain a certain date, so when I type in a cell "20150520") it work fine, but when I calculate or copy the date  from another cell, the filter don't work anymore

```
=filter(import!A1:E77;import!C1:C77=G31)

G31 ="20150520"   works fine
G31 =TODAY()      #N/A
G31 =text(TODAY();"yyyymmdd")   #N/A
```

How can I compose cell 31, in a way the filter will work

(sheet 'import' has imported data with dates like 20150520(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your legacy file may be formatting it as a number, in which case you need to change your G31 to a number as well.  Try
`=Int(Text(Today(),"yyyymmdd"))`

Comment: Great this one did it!